# AWS CloudFormation - cfn-init source file into env

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I would like to source a file containing many environment variable exports into the cf-init environment.

```
01_source_vars:
cwd: "/opt/easy-rsa"
test: "test -e /opt/easy-rsa/vars"
command: "source /opt/easy-rsa/vars"
```

I see that there is an "env" property for commands in cfn-init, however how can I use that when sourcing a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `env` property is optional.
I am not sure if you can use the variable into another set of command.
If you want to use it within the command, you can use multiple commands in the `command` using `\n`
You can specify more than one command under that command line using \n for executing the command.

Please check this code below.

```
command: "source file\n echo $variable\n ..."
```

If you have really long command, you can use the `Fn::Join` to simplify the value of command.